# Prove a vector space without defined operations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a set $C$ of all cyclic functions, a continuous real function $f$ is cyclic if $f(x) = f(x+2\pi)$ for all $x \in R$, and $f \cdot g = \int fg \, \,\mathrm{d}x$. I know that in order to prove a vector space over $R$, I need to prove the various addition/multiplication axioms, but here I'm not sure how to start off with what I'm given.

How can I start this proof?

Comment: You can't do this for _all_ cyclic functions, because $fg$ is typically not integrable. You have to restrict to square-integrable functions, or maybe continuous ones.

Comment: Either just go ahead and show the properties one by one, or if you already know that the set of *all* real functions is a vector space, you need only show that this is a sub-space (for which there are simpler criteria). - By the way, it seems ouy want to show that this is  a vecotr space *with a scalar product*. However, the integral you wrote need not even exist for all cyclic $f,g$.

Comment: Realized I miswrote the definition of f - forgot to specify it is a continuous real function, and edited my post to show this. Does this change anything?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My question is I'm not sure how I can show the properties since I'm not given definitions for addition/multiplication - or can I assume I already have those?

Comment: The sum is the pointwise sum.

Comment: So could I assume $f(x+2\pi) = f(x) + f(2\pi)$?

Comment: You *can't* assume $f(x+2\pi) = f(x) + f(2\pi)$.

Comment: The pointwise sum is defined as $(f+g)(x) = f(x )+ g(x)$.